# LibreOffice Math not working... how to start troubleshooting?

Tags: 10.04, libreoffice

After update to LibreOffice 3.5, I can no longer create/edit equations with Math.

If I insert an equation or try to edit an old one, I will not get the windows split at the bottom of the screen where I can write the text.

What can I do to troubleshoot this? Is it a known issue (I haven't found any info on it, anyway)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the following solution:

Please try this:

- close LibreOffice
- rename `~/.libreoffice` and `~/.openoffice.org` if you find them
- rename `~/.config/libreoffice`
- restart LibreOffice : it should create a new clean profile without any old
  data from OOo and previous version of LO
- try LO-Math again

Comment: Trying that... It solved the issue... .The only minor annoyance is that I have to reconfigure toolbars and some plugins, I think. But thanks a lot anyway.

Comment: Yes, of course, because LO recreates all new default configuration files :)